# Jquery click issue with the Menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I have two tabs on top of my website named Business and Personal. When the page loads for the first time the items of the Business tab are shown in the bar below to the tabs.By clicking on the Perosnal it shows the personal items. This is working fine for me. Now I want to change something in the code, when I click on any Personal Menu Items the page refreshes, and it again shows the Business menu items.
Look at the [website](http://flomobile.co.nz/) here

Here is my Jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.business-tab').show();
    $('.personal-tab').hide();
    $('.business-tab #block-nice_menus-2').hide();
    $('.business-top').children().css('color','#00A2C8');
    $('.personal-top').children().css('color','#000000');
    $('.business-top').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).children().css('color','#00A2C8');
        $('.personal-top a').css('color', '#000000');
        $(this).css('margin-bottom', '0px');
        $('.personal-tab').hide();
        $('.business-tab').show();
        $('.business-tab #block-nice_menus-2').hide();
    });
    $('.personal-top').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).children().css('color','#00A2C8');
        $('.business-top a').css('color', '#000000');
        $(this).css('margin-bottom', '0px');
        $('.personal-tab').show();
        $('.business-tab').hide();
        $('.personal-tab #block-nice_menus-2').show();
        $('.personal-tab #block-nice_menus-1').hide();
    });

});
```

I know when the page refreshes it execute the code which I written in document ready. When I click on any item under the Personal Menu, after the page refresh it goes again to the Business Menu and its items. I don't want that instead of it I want personal items to be shown. How can I do this ? Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my question. I found  the solution so I just want to share it so anybody else can be benefitted from the answer.
I have store the current url and use it to solve my problem. Lets have a look at the updated jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var href = $(location).attr('href');
var substr = href.split('/');
var currentUrl = substr[3];
if( currentUrl == 'personal-mobile' ) {
    $( '.personal-tab' ).show();
    $( '.business-tab' ).hide();
    $( '.personal-tab #block-nice_menus-1' ).hide();
    $( '.personal-top' ).children().css('color','#00A2C8');
    $('.business-top a' ).css('color', '#000000');
}
else {
    $( '.business-tab' ).show();
    $( '.personal-tab' ).hide();
    $('.business-top').children().css('color','#00A2C8');
    $('.personal-top').children().css('color','#000000');
}

$('.business-tab #block-nice_menus-2').hide();

$('.business-top').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children().css('color','#00A2C8');
    $('.personal-top a').css('color', '#000000');
    $(this).css('margin-bottom', '0px');
    $('.personal-tab').hide();
    $('.business-tab').show();
    $('.business-tab #block-nice_menus-2').hide();
});
$('.personal-top').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children().css('color','#00A2C8');
    $('.business-top a').css('color', '#000000');
    $(this).css('margin-bottom', '0px');
    $('.personal-tab').show();
    $('.business-tab').hide();
    $('.personal-tab #block-nice_menus-2').show();
    $('.personal-tab #block-nice_menus-1').hide();
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [cookie](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html).

Append some code to your `click()` events that sets a cookie telling the client whether they are browsing in the business or personal side.  I'm not going to paste code because I'll just copy code directly from the link I posted.  But in your `click()` events you'll want to add

```
setCookie("navigation_side", 1, 1);
```

Where the second argument tells you which side they are navigating on.  I just chose int, you can choose string, boolean, whatever.

Then on the top of your code, you will have

```
if ( getCookie("navigation_side") === 1 ) {
    $('.business-tab').show();
    $('.personal-tab').hide();
} else {
    $('.business-tab').hide();
    $('.personal-tab').show();        
}
```

Make sure you set appropriate expire times!  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have found a another simple way to do it. I will post it.